# How to update handle location on slider of D3js dynamic chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**[Here is a fiddle of a simple sample chart.](https://jsfiddle.net/rwhal06/tcbza92p/2/)**

I am **new** to learning about [D3.js](https://d3js.org/).

**I've been unable to figure out through tutorials or [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki)** how to create a tooltip like Mike Bostock did in his amazing [Rent Versus Buy calculator in the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/upshot/buy-rent-calculator.html), shown here:

[image]

I've tried to look at his source code but haven't had luck figuring it out.

In [my sample fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwhal06/tcbza92p/2/), I have the following code (and a lot more):

```
 var handle = slider.append("g").attr("class", "g-parameter-value handle");
 var initialXPos = xAxisScale(chartEl.attr("data-value"));
 handle.append("path").attr("d", "M-5.5,-2.5v10l6,5.5l6,-5.5v-10z")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + initialXPos + "," + -6 + ")");
 handle.append("text").style("text-anchor", "middle").attr("y", 20).attr("dy", ".71em");
```

I'm not sure why the handle doesn't move when dragged [even though it successfully changes the values of the input box and of any related charts (not shown in the fiddle)].

I also haven't been able to figure out how to "fix" and format the numeric value (resulting from the dragging) that gets put into the input text box.

Even pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three necessary changes (but you'll need more than that):

1. `handle` is a `<path>`, and paths don't have a `x` attribute. So, the first change is:

   ```
   handlePath.attr("transform", "translate(" + xAxisScale(h) + ",0)");
   ```
2. As you can see, I'm defining a new variable here:

   ```
   var handlePath = handle.append("path").attr("d", "M-5.5,-2.5v10l6,5.5l6,-5.5v-10z")
       .attr("transform", "translate(" + initialXPos + "," + -6 + ")");
   ```
3. In your input, just use `h`:

   ```
   input.property('value', h);
   ```

However, there is an additional problem: you don't have a function called `drawAllCharts`. So, you'll have to create a specific *update* function to change the bars.

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bh58u8ks/